# Why does gl_speech return errors when using for loop, but not for each individual file? Using tryCatch

Tags: r, for-loop, speech-to-text, google-speech-api, google-language-api

I just recently started using R, and the package `googleLanguageR` - it's great!

I have over 400 .flac files (ca. 20 seconds each) that I would like to convert into text, using `gl_speech`.

I wrote the following loop:

```
for (i in files) {
  possibleError <- tryCatch({ 
    participantid = str_sub(i, 1, 3)
    patha = paste(path_in, i, sep='')
    result <- gl_speech(patha, 
                     sampleRateHertz = 44100L,
                     customConfig = my_config)
    transcript2 <- subset(result$transcript, select=-c(languageCode, channelTag))
    transcriptid <- cbind(participantid, transcript2)
    write_delim(as.data.frame(transcriptid),file.path(path_in,paste0(participantid,'_text.csv')))
  }, 
    error = function(e) e)
  
    if(inherits(possibleError, "error"))  next 
  
    }
```

For completeness, my_config is:

```
my_config <- list(audioChannelCount = 2, 
                  encoding = "FLAC",
                   maxAlternatives = 30,
                  languageCode = "en-US",
                  model = "video"
)
```

I do this for 2, 5 or 10 files at a time. Several of them return errors.
The error message is:

```
ℹ 2020-10-08 20:07:56 > Request Status Code:  408
Error : lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       <!DOCTYPE html> <html lang=en> 
                     (right here) ------^

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 408 (Request Timeout)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>408.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>Your client has taken too long to issue its request.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
```

However, when I later run the files that returned errors individually, `gl_speech` does not return this error.

Is there a different way to loop over several files that will avoid as many errors?

Comment: Try to slow down your for loop by adding a `Sys.sleep(1)` or something similar. Error 408 means request timeout. The reason for this failure could be that the Google server limits how many requests you can send within a certain time interval. So you should reduce your request frequency.

Comment: googleAuthR  (the API handling library dependency for googleLanguageR) will now retry 408 errors, which will save you needing to write code to handle it.